# Custom Marker with Mapdeck

Tags: r, shiny, mapdeck

I am trying to create custom Markers (e.g. a picture or symbol) for a scatter plot in mapdeck.

Example:

```
  test <- st_as_sf(as.data.frame(list("lon" = 40, "lat" = 60)), coords = c("lon", "lat"))
  map <- mapdeck( style = mapdeck_style("light")) %>%
    add_geojson(test)
```

This plots a point with the standard purple circle:
[image]

Now I want instead of the circle an awesome marker or something similar.
I already tried to expand the sf by

```
test$["marker-symbol"] <- "rocket"
```

Which does not work.
Is there anyway to customize the markers in mapdeck?

Comment: This is not currently possible in mapdeck.